# Swift-NIO secured websocket server

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, server, swift-nio

I am trying to create websocket server and client in my iOS app, which i successfully managed to do with the help of sample implementation here. (https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/tree/master/Sources/NIOWebSocketServer) - so current working situation is, i run the websocket server when app launches and then I load the client in a webview which can connect to it.

Now my problem is I want my server to secured websocket server (Basically connect to the websocket server from a HTTPS html page)

I am new to network programming and Swift-nio documentation is lacking to say the least. As far as I understand I could use (https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-transport-services)

I found this thread which is exactly what I need - https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-transport-services/issues/39 - I could disable the TLS authentication as I dont care in my usecase as long as I could get the websocket connected.

So my question is how to I extend my client (https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/tree/master/Sources/NIOWebSocketClient) and server (https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/tree/master/Sources/NIOWebSocketServer) to use swift-nio-transport-service.

I could add the `NIOSSLContext` and stuff but I think I need to add the `EventLoopGroup` and new `bootstrap` methods. I know the answers is right there.... but I just cannot seem to pinpoint it.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

To translate a simple `NIO` Server to a `NIOTransportServices` one, you need to make the following changes:

1. Add a dependency on `NIOTransportServices` to your server.
2. Change `MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup` to `NIOTSEventLoopGroup`.
3. Change `ClientBootstrap` to `NIOTSConnectionBootstrap`.
4. Change `ServerBootstrap` to `NIOTSListenerBootstrap`.
5. Build and run your code.

Some `ChannelOption`s don’t work in `NIOTransportServices`, but most do: the easiest way to confirm that things are behaving properly is to quickly test the common flow.

This doesn’t add any extra functionality to your application, but it does give you the same functionality using the iOS APIs.

To add TLS to either `NIOTSConnectionBootstrap` or `NIOTSListenerBootstrap`, you use the `.tlsOptions` function. For example:

```swift
NIOTSListenerBootstrap(group: group)
    .tlsOptions(myTLSOptions())
```

Configuring a `NWProtocolTLS.Options` is a somewhat tricky thing to do. You need to obtain a `SecIdentity`, which requires interacting with the keychain. Quinn has discussed this somewhat [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/98029).

Once you have a `SecIdentity`, you can use it like so:

```swift
func myTLSOptions() -> NWProtocolTLS.Options {
    let options = NWProtocolTLS.Options()
    let yourSecIdentity = // you have to implement something here
    sec_protocol_options_set_local_identity(options.securityProtocolOptions, sec_identity_create(yourSecIdentity)
    return options
}
```

Once you have that code written, everything should go smoothly!

---

As an extension, if you wanted to secure a NIO server on Linux, you can do so using [swift-nio-ssl](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-ssl). This has separate configuration as the keychain APIs are not available, and so you do a lot more loading of keys and certificates from files.

Comment: I managed to get the Client & Server running with NIOTransportServices as you suggested. So now I am trying to get `SecIdentity` to work. So I guess `sec_protocol_options_set_peer_authentication_required(options.securityProtocolOptions, false)`is still broken? Do I need to get a self signed certificate - there is no way around it? I know its not the recommeded way but for my usecase I dont need TLS verification. I also tried `.tlsOptions(.init())`to remove TLS but it didnt work.

Comment: Currently stuck at `SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the library` + `SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:NO_CERTIFICATE_SET:`.  -- Will try to generate a self signed certificate  - but it would be nice if I could avoid burning the CPU cycles in the verification process as I dont need it.

Comment: @Lukasa: Any chance you could provide an example of doing this with swift-nio-ssl instead of NIOTransportServices? I'm having a hell of a time figuring out what the proper steps are.

Comment: Hey Bryan, your answer appears to contain the correct example.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a secure websocket without using `SecIdentity` or `NIOTransportServices`, so based on @Lukasa's hint about `swift-nio-ssl` I cobbled together an example that appears to work correctly.

I dunno if it's correct, but I'm putting it here in case someone else can benefit. Error-handling and aborting when the `try`'s fail is left out for brevity.

```
let configuration = TLSConfiguration.forServer(certificateChain: try! NIOSSLCertificate.fromPEMFile("/path/to/your/tlsCert.pem").map { .certificate($0) }, privateKey: .file("/path/to/your/tlsKey.pem"))
let sslContext = try! NIOSSLContext(configuration: configuration)
            
let upgradePipelineHandler: (Channel, HTTPRequestHead) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> = { channel, req in
                
    WebSocket.server(on: channel) { ws in

       ws.send("You have connected to WebSocket")

       ws.onText { ws, string in
           print("Received text: \(string)")
       }
                
       ws.onBinary { ws, buffer in
           // We don't accept any Binary data
       }
                
       ws.onClose.whenSuccess { value in
           print("onClose")
       }
   }
}

self.eventLoopGroup = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 2)
let port: Int = 5759
let promise = self.eventLoopGroup!.next().makePromise(of: String.self)
            
_ = try? ServerBootstrap(group: self.eventLoopGroup!)
                
    // Specify backlog and enable SO_REUSEADDR for the server itself
    .serverChannelOption(ChannelOptions.backlog, value: 256)
    .serverChannelOption(ChannelOptions.socketOption(.so_reuseaddr), value: 1)
                
    .childChannelInitializer { channel in
                    
        let handler = NIOSSLServerHandler(context: sslContext)
        _ = channel.pipeline.addHandler(handler)
              
        let webSocket = NIOWebSocketServerUpgrader(
            shouldUpgrade: { channel, req in
                return channel.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture([:])
            },
            upgradePipelineHandler: upgradePipelineHandler
        )
              
        return channel.pipeline.configureHTTPServerPipeline(
            withServerUpgrade: (
                upgraders: [webSocket],
                completionHandler: { ctx in
                     // complete
                })
        )
    }.bind(host: "0.0.0.0", port: port).wait()

_ = try! promise.futureResult.wait()
try! server.close(mode: .all).wait()
```